# How To: Manage singletons of similar type in Prism with DI/IoC

Tags: xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, inversion-of-control, prism

*Apologies in advance…* I’m new to DI/IoC, Prism and it’s been a long 12 hour day!

The project I’m working on must support communications for TcpIp, Bluetooth LE, and (*Serial if available*). Each connection type will implement **IConnection** *(see below)*, and a type specific interface (i.e. **IBluetoothConnection, ITcpIpConnection, and ISerialConnection**) to encapsulate the respective connection parameters. (Baud Rate, Parity, Flow Control, IP Address, Port #, etc…)

```cs
public interface IConnection
{
  bool Connected { get; }    
  bool Connect();
  bool Disconnect();
  bool Tx(string message);
  string Rx();
}

public interface IBluetoothLeConnection : IConnection
{
  int BaudRate { get; set; }
  int Parity { get; set; }
  int FlowControl { get; set; }
}

public interface ITcpIpConnection : IConnection
{
  string IP { get; set; }
  int Port { get; set; }
}

public interface ISerialConnection : IConnection
{
  string CommPort { get; set; }
  int BaudRate { get; set; }
  int Parity { get; set; }
  int FlowControl { get; set; }
}
```

I plan to register all three as singletons.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IBluetoothConnection, BluetoothLeConnection>();
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ITcpIpConnection, TcpIpConnection>();
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ISeialConnection, SerialConnection>();
```

Define ***IConnection Connection*** in ***ViewMainBase***, and then point it to the chosen concrete connection at runtime.

**Questions**

Will this work?

Is there a better way (***best practice***) or ***(DI/IoC magic)*** to accomplishing this?

Should I create a ***ConnectionManager*** class, and inject all three IConnection types into the constructor and let it manage the active connection?

Comment: Why are `IBluetoothLeConnection`, `ITcpIpConnection`, and `ISeialConnection` interfaces? How are they polymorphic? Will there be more than one implementation of each of them?

Comment: Hey @MarkSeemann they are polymorphic as each interface implements IConnection  I'll probably implement an abstract base class for IConnetion and subclass the other three from it.

Comment: `IConnection` is already polymorphic. Why do you need further polymorphism?

Answer (score 0):

> Will this work?

Yes.

> Is there a better way (best practice) or (DI/IoC magic) to accomplishing this?

I'd refactor the `ref` parameter from `Rx` into something else because it's not easily mockable when you're writing your tests using a framework like Moq.

> Should I create a ConnectionManager class, and inject all three IConnection types into the constructor and let it manage the active connection?

Yes.